# How to decode a URL encoded like this in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, decode

I have a script with this function to encode URLs, but I don't know **how to decode it**:

```js
function app_base64_encode(e) {
  return btoa(
    encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(e, n) {
      return String.fromCharCode("0x" + n);
    })
  );
}

function app_base64_decode(e) {
  //...
}

console.log(app_base64_encode("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054396/how-to-decode-a-url-encoded-like-this-in-javascript"))
```

Comment: Posting a sample URL and its encoded format would be helpful

Comment: Your replace undoes what `encodeURIComponent` did. Whats the point?

Comment: @tkausl I am not the creator of this function and I don't know if it is really ok, but I would like to be able to decode its URLs. Sorry for my bad English and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems `atob` is enough

```js
function app_base64_encode(e) {
  return btoa(
    encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(e, n) { // undo the encode for some reason
      return String.fromCharCode("0x" + n);
    })
  );
}

function app_base64_decode(e) {
  return atob(e)
}

const url = app_base64_encode("%0A%0D") 

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054396/how-to-decode-a-url-encoded-like-this-in-javascript%0A%0D");

console.log(url)
console.log(app_base64_decode(url))
```